# How to keep doc file contents in same Format after replacing a text

Tags: java, file, io, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a doc file. I am replacing the word "location" by "USA" using Java program. But the doc file loses its format.

Here is my code:

```
replaceText(String path, String fileName, String text, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String newFileName = null;
    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(path+"/doc/"+fileName);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        newFileName = request.getRealPath("") + "/doc/"+text+".doc";
        OutputStream writer= new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();

        for( int i=0; i<paragraphs .length; i++ ) {
            paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("location",text);
            byte[] contentInBytes = paragraphs[i].getBytes();
            writer.write(contentInBytes);
        }
        writer.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newFileName;
}
```

Comment: I am using apache-poi library.

Comment: You are just writing the paragraph text, there is a lot of other stuff in a word file that you need to copy as well.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/605944/open-source/edit-doc-docx-file-Java) out! Can be of some help to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the way to replace text without losing the format.
I used `Apache POI`.

These are the jar files:

`poi-3.9-20121203.jar`, `poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar`

Here is the code:

```
 try
{
    URL url = new URL("localhost:8080/testproject/downloads/fileName.doc");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
    newFileName = request.getRealPath("") + "/downloads/newFile.doc";
    OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

    doc.getRange().replaceText("Location", "USA");
    doc.write(writer);
    writer.close();
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this exception: org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndian.getUnsignedByte([BI)I